# MathJax is not working properly when trying to modify the contents of the <p> tag

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

I have been trying to make a MathJax interpreter using JavaScript, HTML and MathJax. I have done all of the default inclusions of the MathJax libraries etc. and one feature of the web application is to be able to type in some LaTeX code and look at the output when a button is pressed. However, when I run the program nothing changes, and all that happens is that the text box which contains the *output* just has the raw output outputted into it.
For Example:

```
// My LaTeX code:
\[x=5\]
// the expected output when the button is clicked:
x = 5
// what I do get:
\[x=5\]
```

I have tried numerous things, but I cant seem to get it to work. Here is my code:

```
var input_text = document.getElementById("mathjax_input_area");
var output_p   = document.getElementById("mathjax_output_area");

output_p.innerHTML = input_text.value;
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, 'output_p']);
```

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, string])`, the string is supposed to be the ID of an element in the page, not the name of a variable in your code.  You could either use

```js
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, output_p]);
```

to use the actual DOM element itself (stored in the variable) or

```js
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, 'mathjax_output_area']);
```

so that you have passed the actual ID of the element to be processed.  Either should work.

Comment: `'mathjax_output_area'` is an element.

Comment: @sciencepi, not according to your code.  It is the ID of an element (something like `<p id="mathjax_output_area">`.  The element is the `p` element, and that is what the `output_p` variable holds.  As the third entry of the array passed to `MathJax.Hub.Queue()`, it is a string (not an element), and `MathJax.Hub.Typeset` uses that string as the id of an element and uses `document.getElementById()` as you did above to locate the actual DOM element.  In any case, using `'output_p'` as the third item in the array is certainly not correct, given the limited details you have provided.